# highlighting section of website after redirect

Tags: javascript, onclick, lightbox

So i've got a lightbox on my website where there's a link within.

When the user clicks the link he gets taken to domain.com/sub#target

The targeted area is quite small so it's really important to highlight it.

This is how far i've gotten:

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mt9z6d7k/1/

```
function focuss (id) {
        var divs = document.getElementsById('u_0_3');

        var count = divs.length; 
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (divs[i].className == 'focus_div'){
                divs[i].onclick = highlight(id);
            }
        }
}

function highlight(id) {

    document.getElementById(id).style.borderColor = '#ff0000';
}
```

the solution must be in javascript unfortunately. If anyone could help me i would appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsById` is not a JS function.
If you want to target multi elements by id, use `document.querySelectorAll('#u_0_3')`.

I must warn you, valid HTML doesn't allow you to repeat the same id on multiple elements. I suggest you use a class, like the `focus_div` above, by doing `document.querySelectorAll('.focus_div')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('focus_div')`.

Here's a working fiddle using multiple ids: http://jsfiddle.net/7g4t9yxo/1/

Notice that I add `focuss('u_0_3');` to the end to activate the behavior.

Comment: thank you very much for your effort!. I've updated your js-fiddle to suit the real scenario.

if you would like to help me to actually make it work on the website i would be forever greatful!

url: http://designdelicatessen.com/return-policy/

at the bottom (footer) you can see the email showing. This is the element i want to highlight. 

Open browser-console and paste the code and you can see that it actually isn't working :/

Updated JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7g4t9yxo/2/

Comment: I simplified your function: http://jsfiddle.net/g5162fhf/1/. Let me know if it works.